# How to return the index of the list item

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have the following list in `Python`:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,'inf'],[6,7],['nan',10]]
```

How can I return the index of the items that contain `'inf'` or `'nan'`?

**EDIT-1**

The first thing I thought about is to make an if-statement, as follows:

```
if (float('inf') in i) or (float('nan') in i)
```

But, didn't know how to go about returning the index value.

**EDIT-2**

The question that has been marked as duplicate didn't actually answer my question.

Thanks.

Comment: Any attempt from your side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I have added that as an edit to my question. I just created an if-statement, but didn't know how to go about returning the index value

Comment: @Simplicity: not a pure duplicate, since that is for a single index.

Comment: Are `inf` and `nan` really strings as indicated by the question or numeric values like in your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can iterate over the list and check for `nan` or `inf`:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,'inf'],[6,7],['nan',10]]

for y in x:
    if 'inf' in y:
        print(x.index(y),y.index('inf'))
    elif 'nan' in y:
        print(x.index(y), y.index('nan'))
```

the result will be:

```
2 1
4 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you added an attempt! We SO users love when folks show their work per say before asking a question. It shows that you are genuinely care about the problem you're trying to solve and not just here for a *free-work* service.

That being said, I like the simplicity of a list comprehension here:

```
>>> [(i, j) for i, seq in enumerate(x) for j, item in enumerate(seq) if item == 'inf' or item == 'nan']
[(2, 1), (4, 0)]
```

A more concise version of the above that takes advantage of sets and their performant membership checks:

```
>>> [(i, j) for i, seq in enumerate(x) for j, item in enumerate(seq) if item in {'inf', 'nan'}]
```

What we do here is **(1)** iterate through the nested list in a nested order, **(2)** check to see if our item matches the conditions you laid out, **(3)** capture the index of that position via the result of our `enumerate()` call.

**Suggested Readings:**

- [Python Strings](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings)
- [Enumerate function](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
[(i, j) for i, outer in enumerate(x) for j, inner in enumerate(outer ) if inner in ['inf','nan']]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made